# JPA OneToMany persist with CascadeType.ALL doesn't persist child

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, persist

I've got the question about using JPA with OneToMany relationship (bidirectional) along with CascadeType.ALL. Basing on vlad post (https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/), persisting in OneToMany relationship using CascadeType.ALL, should also persist

```
Post post = new Post();
post.setName("Hibernate Master Class");

Comment comment1 = new Comment();
comment1.setReview("Good post!");
Comment comment2 = new Comment();
comment2.setReview("Nice post!");

post.addComment(comment1);
post.addComment(comment2);

session.persist(post);
```

But, in my case:

```
//Entity SharedAdvertisementKey
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="SHARED_AD_ID", nullable=false)
private SharedAdvertisement sharedAdvertisement;

//Entity SharedAdvertisements
@OneToMany(mappedBy="sharedAdvertisement", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<SharedAdvertisementKey> sharedAdvertisementKey = new ArrayList<>();
```

It's only working when i link both sides of entities before persisting the owner of relationship:

```
sharedAdvertisementKey.setSharedAdvertisement(sharedAdvertisement);
sharedAdvertisement.addSharedAdvertisementKey(sharedAdvertisementKey);
```

So the main question is: Should I take care of both sides always, even if there is a CascadeType.All on the owner of relationship side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing two very different concepts.

A `CascadeType` deals with what actions cascade to relations.  When specifying `CascadeType.ALL`, you are telling the persistence provider that whenever you persist, merge, or remove that entity, those actions are to be replicated to the relations.

But in order for cascade operations to work, you must first make sure that the relationship is managed correctly.  If you look at Vlad's post, you'll notice two very important methods on `Post`.

```
public void addDetails(PostDetails details) {
  this.details = details;
  details.setPost( this );
}

public void removeDetails() {
  this.details.setPost( null ); 
  this.details = null;
}
```

These methods make sure that the relationship between a `PostDetails` and a `Post` is properly maintained based on your requirements.  So assuming the following mapping:

```
public class Post {
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "post", orphanRemoval = true)
  private PostDetails details;
}
```

You could perform the persistence operation of both of them as follows:

```
PostDetails details = new PostDetails();
details.setUser( currentUser );
Post post = new Post();
post.addDetails( details );
session.persist( post );
```

You notice I used the `addDetails` rather than the typical `setDetails` because I wanted to make sure that the relationship between `Post` and `PostDetails` was initialized.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've not noticed that. Your answer helped me with removing any doubts as to my question.